# How to use four_button.js plugin in Datatables 1.10

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm start to use Datatables 1.10 versión but i have problems to use this option "sPaginationType" : 'four_button' when initializing my datatables

In the version 1.9.4 , I used previously works correctly

My datatables version
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js
My four_button version
https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.17/pagination/four_button.js

```
 table = $('#tabla-informes').DataTable({
        "sDom" : "",
        "sPaginationType" : 'four_button',
        "aoColumns" : aoColumns,
        "aoColumnDefs" : [ {"bVisible" : false, "aTargets" : [ 0 ]} ],
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "/informacion/ajaxLista",
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
  }) ....
```

Browser crash 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTidi.jpg

Thanks, all

Comment: It looks like most of your options are still using the older version. For example, the 1.10 version doesn't use "sPaginationType", it uses "pagingType". https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType

Comment: Hi, thanks! i try "pagingType" and the same result.

Comment: I can't really tell how you're implementing your table without more of your code. Are you using local or server side data? My advice would be to start with a zero configuration and add options one at a time from there. Here's an example of the zero configuration option. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html